# How To Update Deeply Nested Dictionaries of An Unknown State?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have dictionary 3 levels deep.  I won't know if the keys exist or not.  If they exist I need to update the value.  If they don't exist I need to add the key & value.

Here's the code I have... but it is a mess.  There has to be a cleaner more elegant way to do this???

Suggestions???

```
def update_balances_cache(client_name, exchange_name,
                      api_key_nickname, balances,
                      time_checked):

from settings import CACHE

'''
Dictionary structure:
balances = {client_name: {exchange_name: {api_key_nickname: {balances}
                                        }
                             }
               }

CACHE is a class instance holding shared variables between modules.

'''

api_key_level = {api_key_nickname: balances}

exchange_level = {exchange_name: api_key_level}


with CACHE.vlock:
    try:
        # is there a client in the dictionary?
        CACHE.BALANCES_CACHE[client_name]
    except:
        # add client level to dictionary
        CACHE.BALANCES_CACHE[client_name] = exchange_level
        CACHE.BALANCES_CACHE[client_name][exchange_name][api_key_nickname]['last check time'] = time_checked

        return

    # there is a client in the dictionary.  Is the exchange there?
    try:
        CACHE.BALANCES_CACHE[client_name][exchange_name]
    except:
        # add the exchange
        CACHE.BALANCES_CACHE[client_name][exchange_name] = exchange_level
        CACHE.BALANCES_CACHE[client_name][exchange_name][api_key_nickname]['last check time'] = time_checked

        return

    # there is a client & exchange.
    CACHE.BALANCES_CACHE[client_name][exchange_name][api_key_nickname] = api_key_level
    CACHE.BALANCES_CACHE[client_name][exchange_name][api_key_nickname]['last check time'] = time_checked

return
```

Comment: First,  I don't think client_level is what you think it is.  You defined it as a set, not a dict.  Second, you may want to look at a defaultdict for your use case, which automatically creates an item when it doesnt exist in the dict: https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/using-defaultdict-python/

Comment: Habe a look at `dict.setdefault`.

Comment: This isn't working.  It's not throwing errors, but its also not updating the dictionary?? Here's the code.  Is the syntax wrong?          CACHE.BALANCES_CACHE.setdefault(client_name, exchange_level).setdefault(exchange_name, api_key_level)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
def updatedict(a,b):
  for key in b:
      if not key in a or type(a[key]) != dict or type(b[key])!=dict:
          a[key]=b[key]
      else:
          updatedict(a[key],b[key])
x={"a":{"b":{"c":"d"}}}
y={"a":{"b":{"e":"f","c":"d1"},"g":{"h":"i"}},"j":{"k":{"l":"m"}}}
updatedict(x,y)
print(x)
```

the resulting updated x value

```
{'j': {'k': {'l': 'm'}}, 'a': {'b': {'c': 'd1', 'e': 'f'}, 'g': {'h': 'i'}}}
```

Comment: I avoided recursion mostly because of the edge case, client & api key nicknames matching somewhere.  Will this approach cause problems in the edge case that a client_name matches another clients api_key_nickname?

Comment: no,it will not effect since it always goes with the structure. Since ClientName will be in first level and api_key_nickname second level there will not be any problem. Only thing you should make sure is the structure and should order should be same.

Answer (score 0):

using defaultdict from collections module, gotta try out if works for your case

```
from collections import defaultdict
nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict) # this create nested dict with defaultdict

BALANCES_CACHE = nested_dict()
BALANCES_CACHE['client_name']['exchange_name']['api_key_nickname']['last check time'] = 1234
BALANCES_CACHE['client_name']['exchange_name']['api_key_nickname2']['last check time'] = 5678

>>> BALANCES_CACHE['client_name']['exchange_name']['api_key_nickname']['last check time']
1234
>>> BALANCES_CACHE['client_name']['exchange_name']['api_key_nickname2']['last check time']
5678

# default to defaultdict type
>>? BALANCES_CACHE['client_name']['exchange_name']['api_key_nickname2']['blablabla']
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000000001C66A128>, {})
```

To fix it at depth of 4 for your case, try below, hope it works

```
from collections import defaultdict
from settings import CACHE
# this set 4 level depth dict with last level default to int, change accordingly
CACHE.BALANCES_CACHE = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))))

def update_balances_cache(client_name, exchange_name,
                      api_key_nickname, balances,
                      time_checked):

    # from settings import CACHE # move outside function
    api_key_level = {api_key_nickname: balances}
    exchange_level = {exchange_name: api_key_level}

    with CACHE.vlock:
        # update dict
        CACHE.BALANCES_CACHE[client_name].update(exchange_level)
        CACHE.BALANCES_CACHE[client_name][exchange_name].update(exchange_level) # seems like should be api_key_level ?
        CACHE.BALANCES_CACHE[client_name][exchange_name][api_key_nickname].update(api_key_level) # seems no need ?

        CACHE.BALANCES_CACHE[client_name][exchange_name][api_key_nickname]['last check time'] = time_checked
```

Comment: If I used this approach, how would I define the default values for each key upfront?

Comment: it will be of defaultdict type by default

Comment: On this line of code: "nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)" I would need to define the key values pairs 3 levels deep.  As near as I can tell it's using a recursive call, so the resultant dictionary doesn't have the key values above it?

Comment: seems like it, its call recursively to arbritary depth, so can't define default value for the key, what you want the default value or type to be ?

Comment: i draft out some code targeting you case, check it out